# Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 4 in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... taking too much time

Tags: android, flutter

I am new in flutter recently installed flutter in an android studio and run the app but unfortunately, it takes too much time, then I wait 30 to 60 minutes but it not running it stack at

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 4 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

my flutter doctor cmd output is

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

'Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug' usually will take a long time. But once you run it, you can  use hot reload for reloading it in about less than one second. But if it is taking too much time, may be you are having a slower PC, or you are stuck inside a loop, or your phone has been disconnected while gradle was running. Check if you have your cable connected to phone is loose. As flutter is still under development there are lots of things to be updated. Unfortunately there is no other option to cancel the gradle run, so you will have to restart your android studio.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have done all effort but still isn't running

Comment: Are you sure you enabled developers option in your phone, try enabling PTP or FTP instesad of charging only

Comment: yes i am an android develper and learning flutter ,so USB debugging is always on in my smartphone...

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
flutter clean    
flutter pub get  
flutter run
```

and do tell if your having this error on new apps or apps that you have pulled from Github?
and add more info

Comment: Format your answer so that the commands are formatted as code

Comment: My Technical impossibility was solved thanks to you.